# How do I read a specfic HTML table with multiple rows in C#?

Tags: c#, html, linq

I am currently doing a project in my spare time to read from a hockey stats database and have been having trouble for a few days now on getting only the data I want. I am using the HTML Agility Pack to parse and LINQ methods for pinpointing the right table. It points to the right table when I read the header tags , but when I try and read each row of data from the specific table it goes all the way back to the beginning of the html document and starts at the first table. It feels like my second loop is ignoring the location of the table I want. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace HTMLDataGatherer
{
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string htmlCode = "";

        //Simple html doc initialization
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
            htmlCode = 
            client.DownloadString(
            "http://stats.hockeyanalysis.com/ratings.php?db=201415&sit=all&type=individual&teamid=0&pos=skaters&minutes=50&disp=1&sort=PCT&sortdir=DESC.html");
        }

        ReadMe(htmlCode);
    }

    static void ReadMe(String sourceHtml)
    {
        HtmlDocument reader = new HtmlDocument();

        reader.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);

        //'Table 3' as in the table I want is the third one from the top
        var table3 = reader.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();

        //Points to the header tags from the first row
        var headers = table3.SelectNodes("//tr//th");

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        //Adds the header data to 'table' and outputs to console for confirmation
        foreach (HtmlNode header in headers)
        {
            Console.Write(header.InnerText.ToString() + "\t");
            table.Columns.Add(header.InnerText); // create columns from th
        }

        //***************************
        //This starts from first table for some reason
        //I need this foreach to start from the third table, but
        //after it reads the headers it will output rows from the table
        //at the beginning.

        // select rows with td elements
        foreach (var row in reader.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().SelectNodes("//tr[td]"))
        {
            //I am unsure how to access each row of data to write
            Console.Write(row.InnerText.ToString() + "inner\t");
            table.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
        }
        //***************************
        Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

This is the html. I am trying to get past all of the garbage and dropdown menu stuff and go right to the player data.

```
<html><head><title>Stats.HockeyAnalysis.com NHL Individual Player Statistics 201415</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /><meta name="author" content="HockeyAnalysis.com" /><meta name="description" content="Individual player statistics" /><meta name="keywords" content="hockey, nhl, statistics, advanced stats, fancystats, corsi, fenwick, pdo, analytics" /></head></body><!-- BuySellAds Ad Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  var bsa = document.createElement('script');
     bsa.type = 'text/javascript';
     bsa.async = true;
     bsa.src = 'http://s3.buysellads.com/ac/bsa.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);
})();
</script>
<!-- End BuySellAds Ad Code -->

<div class="header"><br><table background-color=#000000><tr><td width=400><a href="index.php"><h1>Stats.HockeyAnalysis.com</h1></a><br><h3>The most complete database of advanced hockey stats</h3><br></td><td valign=top>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- stats.hockeyanalysis.com leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5068178113874808"
     data-ad-slot="9146794890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>



</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="content">
<br>
<center>
<div id="tswcsstabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="teamstats.php">Team Stats</a></li>
<li><a href="ratings.php">Player Stats</a></li>
<li><a href="players.php">Players</a></li>
<!-- <li><a href="2013playoffs/index.php">Playoff Data</a></li> -->
<li><a href="glossary.php">Glossary</a></li>
<!-- <li><a href="about.php">About Ratings</a></li> -->
<li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.hockeyanalysis.com">Blog</a></li>
<!-- <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li> -->
<!-- <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li> -->
<li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<br>
For a new modern interface to these <a href="http://www.puckalytics.com">Advanced NHL Statistics</a> visit <a href="http://www.puckalytics.com">Puckalytics.com</a>.
</div>
</center>
</div>
<br><br>



<form action="ratings.php" method="get">
<center>
<h2>NHL Player Stats/Ratings</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td width=250 align="right">
     Season:
    <select name="db" style="width: 180px">
    <option value="201415" selected >2014-15</option>
    <option value="201314"  >2013-14</option>
    <option value="201213"  >2012-13</option>
    <option value="201112"  >2011-12</option>
    <option value="201011"  >2010-11</option>
    <option value="200910"  >2009-10</option>
    <option value="200809"  >2008-09</option>
    <option value="200708"  >2007-08</option>
    <option value="201315"  >2013-15 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="201214"  >2012-14 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="201113"  >2011-13 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="201012"  >2010-12 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="200911"  >2009-11 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="200810"  >2008-10 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="200709"  >2007-09 (2yr)</option>
    <option value="201215"  >2012-15 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="201114"  >2011-14 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="201013"  >2010-13 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="200912"  >2009-12 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="200811"  >2008-11 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="200710"  >2007-10 (3yr)</option>
    <option value="201115"  >2011-15 (4yr)</option>
    <option value="201014"  >2010-14 (4yr)</option>
    <option value="200913"  >2009-13 (4yr)</option>
    <option value="200812"  >2008-12 (4yr)</option>
    <option value="200711"  >2007-11 (4yr)</option>
    <option value="200914"  >2009-14 (5yr)</option>
    <option value="200813"  >2008-13 (5yr)</option>
    <option value="200712"  >2007-12 (5yr)</option>
    <option value="200814"  >2008-14 (6yr)</option>
    <option value="200713"  >2007-13 (6yr)</option>
    <option value="200714"  >2007-14 (7yr)</option>
    </select>
<br>
     Situation:
    <select name="sit" style="width: 180px">
    <option value="5v5"  >5 on 5</option>
    <option value="5v5home"  >5 on 5 Home</option>
    <option value="5v5road"  >5 on 5 Road</option>
    <option value="5v5close"  >5 on 5, Close</option>
    <option value="5v5close_home"  >5 on 5, Close Home</option>
    <option value="5v5close_road"  >5 on 5, Close Road</option>
    <option value="5v5tied"  >5 on 5, Tied</option>
    <option value="5v5tied_home"  >5 on 5, Tied Home</option>
    <option value="5v5tied_road"  >5 on 5, Tied Road</option>
    <option value="5v5leading"  >5 on 5, Leading</option>
    <option value="5v5leading_home"  >5 on 5, Leading Home</option>
    <option value="5v5leading_road"  >5 on 5, Leading Road</option>
    <option value="5v5trailing"  >5 on 5, Trailing</option>
    <option value="5v5trailing_home"  >5 on 5, Trailing Home</option>
    <option value="5v5trailing_road"  >5 on 5, Trailing Road</option>
    <option value="5v5up1"  >5 on 5, Up 1</option>
    <option value="5v5up2"  >5 on 5, Up 2+</option>
    <option value="5v5down1"  >5 on 5, Down1</option>
    <option value="5v5down2"  >5 on 5, Down2+</option>
    <option value="4v4"  >4 on 4</option>
    <option value="all" selected >All Situations</option>

    <option value="5v4"  >5 on 4 PP</option>
    <option value="4v5"  >4 on 5 SH</option>
    <option value="PP"  >All PP</option>
    <option value="SH"  >All SH</option>

    <option value="f10"  >5 on 5 (ZS Adj.)
    <option value="5v5home_f10"  >5 on 5 Home (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5road_f10"  >5 on 5 Road (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5close_f10"  >5 on 5, Close (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5tied_f10"  >5 on 5, Tied (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5up1_f10"  >5 on 5, Up 1 (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5up2_f10"  >5 on 5, Up 2+ (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5down1_f10"  >5 on 5, Down1 (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5down2_f10"  >5 on 5, Down2+ (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5leading_f10"  >5 on 5, Leading (ZS Adj.)</option>
    <option value="5v5trailing_f10"  >5 on 5, Trailing (ZS Adj.)</option>
    </select>

<br>
    Report:
    <select name="type" style="width: 180px">
    <option value="individual" selected >Individual Stats</a>
    <option value="goals"  >On-ice Goal Stats</a>
    <option value="shots"  >On-ice Shot Stats</a>
    <option value="fenwick"  >On-ice Fenwick Stats</a>
    <option value="corsi"  >On-ice Corsi Stats</a>
    </select>

</td>
<td width=250 align="right">
    Select Team:
    <select name="teamid" style="width: 150px">
        <option value="0" selected >All Teams</option>
        <option value="1"  >Anaheim</option>
        <option value="23"  >Arizona</option>
        <option value="3"  >Boston</option>
        <option value="4"  >Buffalo</option>
        <option value="5"  >Carolina</option>
        <option value="6"  >Calgary</option>
        <option value="7"  >Chicago</option>
        <option value="9"  >Colorado</option>
        <option value="8"  >Columbus</option>
        <option value="10"  >Dallas</option>
        <option value="11"  >Detroit</option>
        <option value="12"  >Edmonton</option>
        <option value="13"  >Florida</option>
        <option value="14"  >Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="15"  >Minnesota</option>
        <option value="16"  >Montreal</option>
        <option value="17"  >Nashville</option>
        <option value="18"  >New Jersey</option>
        <option value="19"  >NY Islanders</option>
        <option value="20"  >NY Rangers</option>
        <option value="21"  >Ottawa</option>
        <option value="22"  >Philadelphia</option>
        <option value="24"  >Pittsburgh</option>
        <option value="25"  >San Jose</option>
        <option value="26"  >St. Louis</option>
        <option value="27"  >Tampa Bay</option>
        <option value="28"  >Toronto</option>
        <option value="29"  >Vancouver</option>
        <option value="30"  >Washington</option>
        <option value="2"  >Winnipeg(Atlanta)</option>
    </select>
<br>
    Select Position:
    <select name="pos" style="width: 150px">
        <option value="skaters" selected >All Skaters</option>
        <option value="forwards"  >Forwards</option>
        <option value="defense"  >Defensemen</option>
        <option value="goalies"  >Goalies</option>
    </select>
<br>
    Minutes Played:
    <select name="minutes" style="width: 150px">
        <option value="50" selected >50</option>
        <option value="100"  >100</option>
        <option value="200"  >200</option>
        <option value="300"  >300</option>
        <option value="400"  >400</option>
        <option value="500"  >500</option>
        <option value="750"  >750</option>
        <option value="1000"  >1000</option>
        <option value="1250"  >1250</option>
        <option value="1500"  >1500</option>
        <option value="2000"  >2000</option>
        <option value="2500"  >2500</option>
        <option value="3000"  >3000</option>
        <option value="4000"  >4000</option>
        <option value="5000"  >5000</option>
        <option value="6000"  >6000</option>
        <option value="7500"  >7500</option>
        <option value="10000"  >10000</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="disp" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="PCT">
<input type="hidden" name="sortdir" value="DESC">
<input type="submit" value="Update Player Stats" />
<br><br>
</center>
</form>

<table border=1 bgcolor=#aaaaaa>
    <tr>
    <th align=left>#</th>
    <th align=left class="td_name"><a href="ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=name&sortdir=ASC">Player Name</a> </th>
    <th align=left width=75>Team</th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=GP&sortdir=DESC >GP</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=toi&sortdir=DESC >TOI</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=igoals&sortdir=DESC >G</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=iassists&sortdir=DESC >A</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ifassists&sortdir=DESC >FirstA</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ipoints&sortdir=DESC >Points</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ishots&sortdir=DESC >Shots</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ifenwick&sortdir=DESC >iFenwick</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=icorsi&sortdir=DESC >iCorsi</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ishpct&sortdir=DESC >ShPct</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=igoals60&sortdir=DESC >G/60</a></th>
    <th width=45><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=iassists60&sortdir=DESC >A/60</a></th>
    <th width=60><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ifassists60&sortdir=DESC >FirstA/60</a></th>
    <th width=60><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ipoints60&sortdir=ASC >Points/60</a></th>
    <th width=60><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ishots60&sortdir=DESC >Shots/60</a></th>
    <th width=60><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=ifenwick60&sortdir=DESC >iFenwick/60</a></th>
    <th width=60><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=icorsi60&sortdir=DESC >iCorsi/60</a></th>
    <th width=55><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=IGP&sortdir=DESC >IGP</a></th>
    <th width=55><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=IAP&sortdir=DESC >IAP</a></th>
    <th width=55><a href=ratings.php?disp=1&db=201415&sit=all&pos=skaters&minutes=50&teamid=0&type=individual&sort=IPP&sortdir=DESC >IPP</a></th>

    </tr>



<tr bgcolor=#eedddd>    <td>   1</td>
    <td><a href=showplayer.php?pid=988>VORACEK, JAKUB</td>
    <td>Philadelphia</td>
    <td><center>      51</center></td>
    <td><center>     939:45</center></td>
    <td><center>    17</center></td>
    <td><center>    41</center></td>
    <td><center>    20</center></td>
    <td><center>    58</center></td>
    <td><center>   143</center></td>
    <td><center>   190</center></td>
    <td><center>   265</center></td>
    <td><center>   11.89</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.09</center></td>
    <td><center>    2.62</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.28</center></td>
    <td><strong><center>    3.70</center></strong></td>
    <td><center>    9.13</center></td>
    <td><center>   12.13</center></td>
    <td><center>   16.92</center></td>
    <td><center>    22.7</center></td>
    <td><center>    54.7</center></td>
    <td><center>    77.3</center></td>
    </tr>




<tr bgcolor=#eedddd>    <td>   2</td>
    <td><a href=showplayer.php?pid=458>MALKIN, EVGENI</td>
    <td>Pittsburgh</td>
    <td><center>      46</center></td>
    <td><center>     894:43</center></td>
    <td><center>    20</center></td>
    <td><center>    32</center></td>
    <td><center>    17</center></td>
    <td><center>    52</center></td>
    <td><center>   144</center></td>
    <td><center>   204</center></td>
    <td><center>   256</center></td>
    <td><center>   13.89</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.34</center></td>
    <td><center>    2.15</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.14</center></td>
    <td><strong><center>    3.49</center></strong></td>
    <td><center>    9.66</center></td>
    <td><center>   13.68</center></td>
    <td><center>   17.17</center></td>
    <td><center>    29.0</center></td>
    <td><center>    46.4</center></td>
    <td><center>    75.4</center></td>
    </tr>




<tr bgcolor=#ddddee>    <td>   3</td>
    <td><a href=showplayer.php?pid=1675>TARASENKO, VLADIMIR</td>
    <td>St. Louis</td>
    <td><center>      50</center></td>
    <td><center>     894:27</center></td>
    <td><center>    26</center></td>
    <td><center>    25</center></td>
    <td><center>    14</center></td>
    <td><center>    51</center></td>
    <td><center>   175</center></td>
    <td><center>   254</center></td>
    <td><center>   340</center></td>
    <td><center>   14.86</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.74</center></td>
    <td><center>    1.68</center></td>
    <td><center>    0.94</center></td>
    <td><strong><center>    3.42</center></strong></td>
    <td><center>   11.74</center></td>
    <td><center>   17.04</center></td>
    <td><center>   22.81</center></td>
    <td><center>    34.7</center></td>
    <td><center>    33.3</center></td>
    <td><center>    68.0</center></td>
    </tr>

etc.
```

I only want the player data which happens to be the third table. If you run this code then it will display the header rows correctly (badly formatted), but then display data rows as if it jumped back up to the first table. Any feedback would be greatly appeciated!

Comment: show us the html which you want to read ...

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the link was broken

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you just looping over the rows from the table you assigned to `table3`? Or to restate - why are you searching for the same table twice?

Comment: Good observation. I had been doing that originally, but it was still going back to the beginning after finding the headers. I tried to do a more direct method call on the rows to see if that had any effect but it produces the same results.